# tileList cells respond to mouse events in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I’m making a Flash game (which is basically a version of the same game), and I’ve used a `tileList` for the board populated with `movieClip` pieces. I would like the pieces to respond to `mouseOver`, `mouseOut`, and `mouseClick` events.

From looking at other question/answers, I get the idea I’ll need a custom `imageCell`. Is that the way to go. I was hoping I could get the responses I want by putting the actions into the `movieClips` themselves as below, but that doesn’t seem to work. 
(btw I’m new to the community but have wound up here several times from Google searches … Thanks for help I’ve received already from you wonderful folks. Cheers.)

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, OverHandler);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, OutHandler);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickHandler);

this.stop();

function OverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
event.target.play();
}

function OutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
event.target.stop();
}

function ClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably set up a base class for all of your pieces in the game that have the events there and ready.. Like so:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Piece extends MovieClip
    {
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Piece()
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, _rollOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, _rollOut);
        }

        /**
         * Called on MouseEvent.CLICK
         */
        protected function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(this + " was clicked");
        }

        /**
         * Called on MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER
         */
        protected function _rollOver(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(this + " was rolled over");
        }

        /**
         * Called on MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT
         */
        protected function _rollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(this + " was rolled off");
        }

        /**
         * Destroys this
         */
        public function destroy():void
        {
            // listeners
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, _rollOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, _rollOut);

            // from DisplayList
            if(parent) parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need click, roll_over or roll_out to do anything unique on certain pieces, just extend and do this:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class MyPiece extends Piece
    {
        override protected function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("mypiece was clicked");
        }
    }
}
```